# Node js keeps connecting even though server is down

Tags: node.js, express

I have a a Node.js server. The problem is sometimes mysql server - not in my server but outside — crashes so get a timeout. The problem is that the external server blocks my IP because my server keeps sending request to the server with no limit.

How can I make the server stop trying and retry in a few minutes after getting a denial from server?

My connection code is:

```
var conCalculos  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: localhost,
    user: "user",
    password: "key",
    database : 'Database',
    multipleStatements:true
});
  
conCalculos.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to use [PoolCluster](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#poolcluster) and set `restoreNodeTimeout`

Comment: Sorry, I´m no to node js. How dow I use it?